# ORA-01017 invalid username/password: login denied

Tags: oracleforms

I'm getting this error while running Oracle Form Builder. What could be the reason behind it?

[image: Invalid Username/password]

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple - enter valid username/password@database combination (i.e. *connection string*).

Comment: And if you've entered what you believe are correct values, then it seems likely that your tnsnames.ora file is incorrect.